# When Creating a DSN Less SQL Connection in Ms Access, How do I specify the Schema?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've done DSN Less 2 different ways, but neither seem to have a way to specify a schema.

I tried specifying to schema like [schema]. but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to get it to link up?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the schema in the connection string, but specify that schema in the table name (or view).

So, the default schema is "dbo".

So for table customers and schema "dbo", you use

```
dbo.Customers.
```

If the schema is sales, or other? then you go:

```
sales.Customers.
```

So the connection to the database is un-changed.

You don't have to (or can) specify the schema in the conneciton - you specifty it in the table name.

Of course the local table name can be ANY table name you want - and you are free to include or not the prefix like this

```
dbo_Customers
Sales_Contacts
```

But, you can could use

```
Customers
Contacts
```

In fact, in most cases, if you doing a migration from a standard Access data file back end to SQL server?

Then you of course will keep the client side (linked) table name as to what it was before, and the linked table name does not have any special meaning in regards to the schema used.

So only the table prefix (dbo.) is how you select/change/use a database schema, and this ONLY applies to the server side name you use when creating a table link. As noted the client side linked table can be any name you want, and it can "only" include the schema if YOU decide to adopt some naming convention.

So, you specify the schema by prefixing the server side table name when re-linking, or creating a table link.

Comment: This is what I tried initially. [dbo].tablename  and  dbo.tablename, neither worked saying table not found.

Comment: Yes, you cna't use [] around the schema for this to work. in fact [] are not supported in ANY case as far as I know. So you can use spaces like   "sales force.My Employees" ------ in that case schema is "Sales Force" and table is "My Employees" - ---- both having spaces in their names.

Comment: I found the problem. As chance would have it, the first table I tried had a schema called 90day. Schemas need to not start with a number in order for them to link without a DSN.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I quite much though both tables and schema could not start with numbers. If you MUST link to that table, and can't rename it? Then create a view server side with a different name - you can then link to that from Access.